# Hiding multiple elements of a specific class or ID using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know if its possible to hide all the HTML elements (divs in my case) with a specific class name or ID using jquery.

Thanks

Thanks for the sympathy, I already know the hide() function but the problem is there are multiple divs which I want hidden but the my code only works on the first on or doesnt work at all. Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(
                            $(".list").hide();                                
                            function divToggle() 
                            { 
                              $(this).children("div.list").slideToggle("fast");
                            });
```

Please assist me in finding what I'm doing wrong.

And Thanks for your patience

Comment: Bit lazy but doesn't deserve a downvote... +1

Comment: Extremely lazy and definitely deserved a down-vote. If you've found jQuery but can't be bothered to read any of the extensive and well presented documentation and then come to SO to get someone else to do your work for you then I'll down vote happily. -1

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$(".class").hide();
```

or an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (when hiding a single element):

```
$("#id").hide();
```

But the ID selector should be **unique**, so in the case of `$("#id")` you shouldn't be trying to select multiple elements...that's definitely a situation for classes.

Comment: Also $('div.[class]').hide(); would work if you just want divs.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('.specific, #specific').hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can hide multiple class also For example,

jQuery('.class1, .class2').hide();

Comment: You just copied and pasted an answer from >3 years ago... What information are you adding here?

Comment: Your answer should be more descriptive please read [how to ask question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)